# Recursive Constructor Invocation in Class

Tags: java, recursion

```
    final List<Tags> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    public void startUp() {
        //load tags from Config text box
        reloadTags();
    }

    @Getter
    @ToString
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    static class Tags  
    {
        private final String tag;
        private final String value;

        //recursive error comes from here
        Tags(String tag, String value)  
        {
            this(tag, value);
        }
    }

   //detect change in Config textbox, update tags
    @Subscribe
    public void onConfigChanged(ConfigChanged configChanged) {
        if (configChanged.getGroup().equals("calculatorpro")) {
            reloadTags();
        }
    }

    //clear current Tags list & update with new tags from Config Text box
    private void reloadTags()
    {
        tags.clear();
        tags.addAll(loadTags(config.customTags()));
    }

    //load tags from Config text box
    private Collection<? extends Tags> loadTags(String textbox)
    {
        List<Tags> swaps = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String line : textbox.split("\n"))
        {
            if (line.trim().equals("")) continue;
            String[] split = line.split("=");
            swaps.add(new Tags(
                    split[0].toLowerCase().trim(),
                    split.length > 1 ? split[1].toLowerCase().trim() : ""
            ));
        }
        return swaps;
    }
```

I get the error: "java: recursive constructor invocation" from my "static class Tags" class.

Im trying to make a list of tag name and value, which I get from a user textbox (config.customTags()). They will be input as a string, in the form of tag=value (oak=255). When a change is detected in the textbox, the old list is cleared, and a new list is created with the new contents of the textbox (done in the function loadTags).

The code is actually off another file created by someone else that works, I just took the parts of it that suit my purpose, but the actual contents are the same but with altered names, so Im not sure why theirs works and is not recursive, but mine does not work and is recursive? [Here](https://github.com/geheur/More-menu-entry-swaps/blob/master/src/main/java/com/hotkeyablemenuswaps/HotkeyableMenuSwapsPlugin.java) is a link to their code (there is a lot of extra functionality in their code that I do not use in mine).

Im a beginner programmer (this is my first java program!), so any information that anyone can provide would be great! (also I apologize if Ive left out any pertinent information, I tried to only share what is related with the error)

Comment: Please avoid linking to code on external sites, especially if it could change at any time, like the branch head of a GitHub project. It’s also hard to figure out which of the 990 lines of code you’re referring to. It’s much better to copy the example into the question text.

Comment: @TimMoore thanks, I will keep that in mind! I only linked the entire code this time as I wasnt sure if I maybe left an important part out of it in my code that could have been causing the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor is calling itself:

```
    //recursive error comes from here
    Tags(String tag, String value)  
    {
        this(tag, value);
    }
```

If the compiler allowed this the constructor would enter an infinite loop when called.

Rewrite it to simply initialise the two fields from the given arguments, like this:

```
    Tags(String tag, String value)  
    {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.value = value;
    }
```

Comment: Wow, such an easy fix. Thanks a lot, I spent a lot of time trying to fix this, scouring through my code and the templates code. I dont understand why the templates code was fully functional, even though it seems just as recursive to me

Comment: Which templates code are you refering to?

Comment: In that example, the constructor `CustomSwap(String option, String target)` calls `this(option, target, null, null)`. Notice that it is a constructor with two arguments calling a constructor with four arguments, so this is not recursive. The four argument version of the constructor doesn’t appear in the code, because it is generated by the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` Lombok annotation.

Comment: As a beginner, I would recommend _not_ using Lombok. It can make it harder to understand what’s going on. Lombok is better as a shortcut for developers who are already proficient with Java IMHO.

Comment: @TimMoore thanks! I wondered why there were 4 arguments in their code, I didnt quite understand it. I tried also passing an extra null argument in my code, but that did not solve it haha. Im not familiar with Lombok yet, so I will take your advice and continue to not use it!

Comment: @jon-hanson theres a link in the OP

Comment: @TravelKidKurty the `@Getter`, `@ToString`, and `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotations that appear in your code are all from Lombok. It is a tool that automatically generates constructor and method implementations for a class based on the fields it declares. When starting out, it’s better to write them out in full to understand how they work.